# Iterating through table lines with cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to iterate through lines with cursor loop and print Hello World message with `line_id` and message from column `line_message` for each line, but I am getting an error:

```
Errors: PROCEDURE CURSOR_PROC
Line/Col: 4/10 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CUR" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SQL_JRIJMVCLEKHINBWFZGYOVYVIR.CURSOR_PROC is invalid
```

And here is my code example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CURSOR_PROC
IS
BEGIN
  cursor cur is select line_id, line_message from TABLE_T;
  open cur;
  for rec in cur LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello world! ' || line_id || ', ' || line_message);
  END LOOP;
END CURSOR_PROC;
/

EXEC CURSOR_PROC;
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: It's been fixed. Please try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could do away with declaring the cursor completely ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CURSOR_PROC
IS

BEGIN
  for rec in (select line_id, line_message from TABLE_T)
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello world! ' || rec.line_id || ', ' || rec.line_message);
  END LOOP;
END CURSOR_PROC;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your cursor definition in the DECLARE block and fully qualify the record as part of the output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CURSOR_PROC
IS
DECLARE
  cursor cur is select line_id, line_message from TABLE_T;
BEGIN
  for rec in cur LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello world! ' || rec.line_id || ', ' || rec.line_message);
  END LOOP;
END CURSOR_PROC;
/

EXEC CURSOR_PROC;
```

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-25917214-FD91-499D-AB39-CE21484AB167

Also, it isn't strictly required to use `OPEN CURSOR` in this context but if you do, always include an explicit `CLOSE CURSOR` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

**cursor cur is select line_id, line_message from TABLE_T;** is a declaration so I have shifted this line before BEGIN. **Open cur** is not needed with for loop and in the loop you need to specify **rec.line_id** instead of line_id. Now it's working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CURSOR_PROC
IS
cursor cur is select line_id, line_message from TABLE_T;
BEGIN
  
  for rec in cur LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello world! ' || rec.line_id || ', ' || rec.line_message);
  END LOOP;
  
END CURSOR_PROC;
```